# Subsetting in R with a mathematical operation

Tags: r, subset

Is it possible to obtain a subset of the dataFrame in R, by passing a mathematical operation to the `subset` function?

`blla <- subset(blla, blla$t1 - blla$t2 == 10)`

This did not work for me. Is there another easy way to achieve such subsetting?

Comment: I think your code should work `set.seed(24);blla <- data.frame(t1=sample(1:30, 20, replace=TRUE), t2= sample(1:6, 20, replace=TRUE));subset(blla, t1-t2==10)`

Comment: When using `subset` (a convenience function), you don't need to call the columns using `blla$` inside it. Just do `subset(iris, Sepal.Length - Sepal.Width > 4)` (as an example with a built in data set) an it should work

Comment: What are the structures of `t1` and `t2`?

Comment: Maybe `blla[as.numeric(blla$t1) - as.numeric(blla$t2) == 10,]` works in your case?

Comment: There is also the possibility that it "doesn't work" because the condition is not fulfilled anywhere in the dataframe. In that case you will probably obtain an output with `<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)`.